# npx runs a node version which does not exist on my machine

Tags: node.js, npm, create-react-app, npx

I tried to run this command `npx create-react-app my-app` and got this error

```
error @typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin@4.5.0: The engine "node" is incompatible with this module. Expected version "^10.12.0 || >=12.0.0". Got "11.13.0"
error Found incompatible module.
```

The weird thing is I used node version 15.0.1 (latest) and yarn version 1.22.10 (latest) and the version that npx used `Got "11.13.0"` which does not exist on my machine.

Anybody face this problem ? Please help, many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

The situation may be different on Windows, but on UNIX-like operating systems (including macOS), you can find the path to the `node` being executed by `npx` with:

```
/usr/bin/env node -p process.execPath
```

This is because the `npx` file starts with `#!/usr/bin/env node`. So you can use `/usr/bin/env node` to execute the same `node` that `npx` will.

`-p` means "print the value" and [`process.execPath`](https://nodejs.org/api/process.html#process_process_execpath) is the path to the executable.

#### Why do you want to do the above and not just use `which node`?

`which` will report aliases, which means that it will report the `node` executable you will see in your shell. That's not what `npx` will use, and that seems a likely possibility to explain why `npx` might use a different Node.js version than you expect.

```
$ alias node=echo
$ node foo
foo
$ which node
node: aliased to echo
$ /usr/bin/env node -p process.execPath
/Users/trott/.nvm/versions/node/v15.0.1/bin/node
$
```

Comment: I tried `/usr/bin/env node -p process.execPath` and it returns `/usr/bin/env`.

Comment: @thelonglqd That's very surprising (to me). What is the output of `/usr/bin/env node -v`?

Comment: `/usr/bin/env` :(

Comment: What operating system are you on?

Comment: I use macOS, what the output it should be ?

Comment: It should be the version of Node.js that `env` finds. (I'm on macOS too.) If you run `/usr/bin/env` with no arguments, does it return a all your environment variable names and values, one per line?

Comment: Oh, and what does your PATH look like? (`echo $PATH`)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/223574/discussion-between-trott-and-thelonglqd).