# Can't install eslint with node 15.10.0

Tags: node.js, npm, eslint

I am having trouble installing eslint on my MacBook pro(big sure)

I have node v15.10 and its asking for 12 so I am not sure what the issue is...

I am not finding much information across the interwebs on this one...

```
bash-3.2$ npm install eslint
npm WARN EBADENGINE Unsupported engine {
npm WARN EBADENGINE   package: undefined,
npm WARN EBADENGINE   required: { node: '12' },
npm WARN EBADENGINE   current: { node: 'v15.10.0', npm: '7.5.3' }
npm WARN EBADENGINE }

up to date, audited 307 packages in 2s

22 packages are looking for funding
  run `npm fund` for details

found 0 vulnerabilities
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [npx runs a node version which does not exist on my machine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64512568/npx-runs-a-node-version-which-does-not-exist-on-my-machine)

Comment: @JimG. It looks kocer.

Here is the output. I am wondering if it has something todo with the package: undefined

```
bash-3.2$ /usr/local/bin/node --version
v15.10.0
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**try installing using this**

```
sudo npm install -g eslint --unsafe-perm=true --allow-root
```

**instead of**

```
npm install eslint
```

Comment: I still get the same output.

Comment: try this then:- npm install eslint --save-dev

Comment: It still says the same thing. Do you think it has something to do with package: undefined in the output?

Comment: try this final:- sudo npm install -g eslint --unsafe-perm=true --allow-root

Comment: money. That did it. But why?

Comment: @Stew8908 `sudo npm install -g eslint --unsafe-perm=true --allow-root`. This works because it installs the package globally(on your pc) and not contain within the project