# create-react-app Says It's Running Deleted Version of node

Tags: node.js, reactjs, nvm

I see multiple people asking the same questions about trying to run `create-react-app`, which then claims an older version of Node is running, even though I uninstalled it via `nvm` multiple times. Here's one example of my attempts to choose a later version of node I have already installed:

```
Mac:react me$ nvm install v16.13.2
v16.13.2 is already installed.
Now using node v16.13.2 (npm v8.1.2)
Mac:react me$ npx create-react-app@latest my-app
You are running Node 12.14.1.
Create React App requires Node 14 or higher. 
Please update your version of Node.
Mac:react me$ npm uninstall -g v12.14.1

up to date, audited 1 package in 317ms

found 0 vulnerabilities
Mac:react me$ nvm use 16.13.2
Now using node v16.13.2 (npm v8.1.2)
Mac:react me$ npx create-react-app@latest my-app
You are running Node 12.14.1.
Create React App requires Node 14 or higher. 
Please update your version of Node.
Mac:react me$
```

I'm running High Sierra, so can't update to the latest/greatest verison of `node`, but as I understand it, I shouldn't have to. How do I fix this so I can actually run `create-react-app` on my system? Many thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Sounds like `npx` isn't using the `nvm` Node version. It's probably a `PATH` ordering issue

Comment: Does this answer your question? [npx runs a node version which does not exist on my machine](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64512568/283366)

Comment: @Phil Sorry to say no - I ran `node -p process.execPath` and it returned `/Users/me/.nvm/versions/node/v16.13.2/bin/node`. Running `/usr/bin/env node -v` returned `v16.13.2`.

Comment: What about `which npx`? It should be in the same path as `node`. For me it's `~/.nvm/versions/node/v16.14.2/bin/npx`

Comment: Does `brew list | grep 'node'` return any results? (if you had installed Node via Homebrew)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only solution that worked for me was to **both** remove `node` and `nvm` via CLI **and** manually. nvm isn't needed on my system anymore, as previous versions of node were for legacy projects I'm no longer working on.

The CLI solution (largely using Homebrew) is discussed many places on SO, including [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11177954/how-do-i-completely-uninstall-node-js-and-reinstall-from-beginning-mac-os-x), and manually also many places online, notably [here](https://stackabuse.com/how-to-uninstall-node-js-from-mac-osx/).