# Node Version not recognised for create-react-app

Tags: node.js, npm, npx

When I try to run create-react-app in the terminal, I keep getting this message saying, 'You are running Node 12.4.0'. But I have updated/reinstalled node many times, and when I run node -v, it tells me I am on the latest version 21.6.1. So why is it telling me I am still on 12.4.0 and not allowing me to install?
Any help appreciated as quite confused! Many thanks!

Desktop % npx create-react-app pizza-menu

You are running Node 12.4.0.

Create React App requires Node 14 or higher.

Please update your version of Node.

Desktop % node -v

v21.6.1

Comment: Not an answer to your question but create-react-app is a dead project and no longer recommended. Try [Vite](https://vitejs.dev/) which doesn't use `npx` either... `npm create vite@latest pizza-menu -- --template react`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [npx runs a node version which does not exist on my machine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64512568/npx-runs-a-node-version-which-does-not-exist-on-my-machine)

Comment: Might be an issue with `npx` pointing to the older Node version. How is Node installed and what OS are you using?

Comment: @Phil I am following a Udemy course which actually recommends to still use create-react-app for the exercises, as it has everything required pre-installed, and use Vita for real-world projects later in the course (I am only at the very beginning)

Comment: I am using Mac OS

Comment: The course is out of date. The good thing about Vite is it generally gets out of your way and lets you focus on building your app

Comment: That may be, but it also specifically says in that video that people will say it is a dead project, but it is still recommended to use for the exercises. And for beginners like me it is much easier to follow using the same tools early on in the course

Comment: @TalRofe I have tried what is suggested there but it also returns the version as 21.6.1

Comment: I understand, just trying to save you more pain in the future. You didn't answer my question about how you installed Node. What do you get for each of `which node` and `which npx`? You could always try avoiding `npx` and use `npm init react-app pizza-menu` (see https://create-react-app.dev/docs/getting-started#npm)

Comment: I can highly recommend installing Node via [asdf](https://asdf-vm.com/guide/getting-started.html). It generally doesn't mess up your executable paths and lets you define specific per-project or global versions of Node.js